# How to use Scaffold-DbContext to generate only DBContext or Tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to know, how to use `Scaffold-DbContext` to generate only `DBContext` and `Tables` in different projects because, I want to generate the `DBContext` in one project, then generate `Tables` in another project. When I use `Scaffold-DbContext`, generate everything in one project and I do not want to delete all the time that I do that.

I read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext but I did not see what I want to do.

Comment: Have you looked at EF Core Power Tools? https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki/Reverse-Engineering

Comment: I have not looked that. I installed and yeap, EF Core Power Tools helped me. Thanks <https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools&ssr=false>